# Laravel 5.2 update last created record

Tags: database, controller, laravel-5, insert-update

I am new to laravel, I have tried a bunch of recommendations but none have worked for what I need.  Do to requirements for design I am splitting my registration into two tables artist and the normal user table.  The problem is email verification is done through the artist table.  After that process has been completed I would simply like to update the last created user in the user table from 0 to 1 in the active column.

I can not figure out how to get this to work.

```
return $this->users()->where('verified')->first()->verified()-   >orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

Then ran update didn't work

```
User::orderby('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

Then tried update didn't work

```
$user = User::find(1)->verified()-   >update(array(
 'Verified' => '1'
   ));
```

Non of the above have worked.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: So you're essentially doing email verification? There is a much simpler way to do this, and the method you have chosen sounds like it sends a verification email out and then when a link is clicked it verifies the most recently created user - what happens then if someone signs up in between this? You would be verifying the wrong person. If it is just email verification you are wanting to do, then I could walk you through a simpler way to do this?

Comment: My set up is they fill out a form and hit submit submit tells them to check there email and click the verification link.  The information they submitted is sent to the database already but they can't access the login or dashboard till they verify there email.  The problem is I want to send the information they filled out to the user table only after they have verified there email.   So the problem is I do not know how to pull the last record created and change the verified status from 0 to 1 in the user table.  What are you saying to do that is easier and can add to both tables through laravel

Comment: Why don't you just assign their `user_id` to that information? And then use that to move the right information once they verify their email?

Comment: I'm new to laravel how do I do that?  I don't get how to pull last record then insert it in new table or how to update specific row and column,  how is attaching user I'd going to help I don't know user I'd will be since it all needs to be automated

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements, and the way you are doing things - you are creating a user during registration (in the `users` table and setting `verified` to 0) and then putting some of their information in an `artists` table until they are verified.

I would add a `users_id` column to your `artists` table and set the value of this to the `id` of the newly created user.

When they verify, you can find their information in your `artists` table using their `user_id` and then move it anywhere you need to.

Comment: How would I know there user_id without having to look it up?

Comment: Well if you do it in the same function as creating the user then you would still be able to access it inside the user object.